# Web page to access bluetooth device

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, bluetooth

I have made an asp.net application designed to manage and optimize warehouse statistics info. The user had to collect and enter all the info manually so I thought it would be way better to  get use of some bar code devices that uses bluetooth for communications to get that info on an automated process.

So I developed an Internet explorer extension that managed the page requests for the bluetooth device and made posts inside a control container with the data.

The fact is that this extension gives me plenty of problems, having to redo the pairing of the devices every now and then as it looses it's functionality after some unknown event. I don't know if it has to do with windows updates or accounts management and rights.

Does anyone knows an alternative, that would be more stable? Perhaps with Java?
Cross-browser would be a plus. In fact I'm headed at mobile devices using android. For the moment, only windows tablets are compatible.

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the problems that where caused by the page not the plugin and left the alternatives temporally aside.

Answer (score 0):

if you are targeting windows tablets, why not using HTML5+Phonegap. This might help.
http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/10/30/announcing-apache-cordova-support-for-windows-phone-8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the objective.